# FCM (Bug) - Send a notification to multiple topics without using the OR operator.

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

Apparently, After having an issue with the (OR ||) operator, As the notification was received when i used the (AND &&) operator and it wasnt when i used (OR ||).

Google confirmed that the OR operator is not working currently in FCM condition field :
[image: FCM - Google]

So is there another way i could send a notification to those who are subscribed to ( TopicA or TopicB or TopicC ) without the (OR ||) operator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update - So ive contacted FCM support & they helped me with a workaround using the (AND &&) And (NOT !) Operators :

> For example, you're trying to send a message to Topic A OR Topic B OR
>   Topic C.
>
> This condition can be converted to the suggested workaround by sending
>   3 messages which looks something like:
>
> 1. Topic A  && !Topic B && !Topic C
> 2. Topic B && !Topic C
> 3. Topic C

Only partial solution i have found so far is to make the condition this way :

```
"'TopicNone' in topics && ('TopicA' in topics || 'TopicB' in topics)"
```

With TopicNone a topic that all devices are subscribed to.
Apparently if i used the OR(||) operators after the AND(&&) operator. It works.

Hoping for google to fixe this bug soon.