# FCM display messages sometimes very slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending display messages to FCM using this request:

```
curl -i -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: ****' -XPOST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d '{"time_to_live":120,"priority":"high","content_available":true,"condition":"'\''4pz87gsel7183b7kcadw1dwzv'\'' in topics OR '\''4njsfszcgd9m765d6suktsz2a'\'' in topics OR '\''match-4i5yvb5co56meztqpc1quflk9'\'' in topics","data":{"event_id":"4i5yvb5co56meztqpc1quflk9_20180715150017","timestamp":1531666817},"notification":{"title":"test123,"body":"\u231a test123","sound":"sound","click_action":"my_action_link","android_channel_id":"ticker"}}'
```

But sometimes this message takes up to 10 minutes to get delivered to the clients? (for iOS and android). How can i achieve a faster delivery?

Comment: May be this post can helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627928/fcm-bug-send-a-notification-to-multiple-topics-without-using-the-or-operator

Comment: As far as i understand this post is related to messages that don't get delivered at all, but my messages are delivered with a big delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found the issue. Firebase is in general very slow delivering messages posted used topics. If you send messages to a specific individual device it gets delivered very fast.

Comment: Yes and if you use conditions like a in topics || b in topics it might take even longer. up to 10 minutes for simple messages. 
Too bad we cannot implement alternatives.

Comment: I'm currently trying to implement sending messages to individuals but the messages are only received with a big delay (minutes).